# Add attributes to Laravel pagination links

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination, laravel-paginate

Please look into my code,
this is my web.php

```
Route::get('test', function (Request $request) {
  $data = MyTableResource::collection(MyTable::paginate(10));
  $headers = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'];
  return view('test.index', compact('data', 'headers'));
});
```

Here is my blade file,

```
<table md-table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach($headers as $header)
                <th><span>{{$header}}</span></th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $d)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$d->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$d->primary_identifier}}</td>
                <td>{{$d->order_date}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class = "table-paginate">
    {{ $orders->links() }}
</div>
```

My problem is that,
when I refresh my page, the URL is
`http://localhost/test?page=1`

And when I click on any link, the URL is just replacing with its number (`http://localhost/test?page=2`), not redirecting.

I inspect the pagination link, it seems like

```
<li class="page-item" aria-current="page">
  <a class="page-link" href="http://amzmarketplace.localhost.tom/test?page=2">2</a>
</li>
```

It is working when I added and attribute to `<a>` tag, that `target="_self"`.

But how can I add this attribute in Laravel pagination URL or is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Check this out, https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went through this already. but couldn't understood. not got the answer. thanks again

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 7.x you can customize URL in route file or controller like:

```
     Route::get('test', function (Request $request) {
      $data = MyTableResource::collection(MyTable::paginate(10));
      $data->withPath('custom/url');
...
    });
```

OR

Also append `sort=votes` to each pagination link, you should make the following call to `appends` in view, like:

```
{{ $data->appends(['sort' => 'votes'])->links() }}
```

Check this out the [laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) documentation link